# How to loop or to repeat periodically task in Android?

Tags: android, repeat

I am quite new to Android, and I am really wondering about is how to loop or to repeat periodically a task. 
In my program, I have UpdateLoc() that sends my gps location to my databse, but I want it to update periodically (whether it be 3 min or 3 hours) without using too much battery and CPU.
The problem is that I have no idea where to start... Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have two options in this case:

1. [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) - This will stay running in the background but use more battery.
2. [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) - You can schedule a task to run in the future to briefly perform an update operation and should use less battery.

Comment: Do you by any chance know where to find an example or sample code for AlarmManager? I really don't know how to use the Android Reference page...

Comment: See `controlAlarm()` https://github.com/willtate/Will-Deux/blob/master/src/com/willtate/willdeux/ItemEdit.java#L254

Comment: Then see the `BroadcastReceiver` named AlarmReceiver which is launched when the Alarm goes off: https://github.com/willtate/Will-Deux/blob/master/src/com/willtate/willdeux/AlarmReceiver.java

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String, long, float, android.location.LocationListener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29)

This will allow you to receive updates only after a particular amount of time has past.

Comment: +1 this is a much better option than my suggestions in this case!