# How to repeat your task in background Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Hello I'm noob in Android. I have already seen this [How to loop or to repeat periodically task in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648724/how-to-loop-or-to-repeat-periodically-task-in-android)

I want to know the different types of ways you can repeat your task in background Android. I know only about `AlarmManager` where you can execute your code after specific time. Is there any other ways also to do same. Any idea ?

Comment: Handler.postDelayed(Runnable, delayMilliseconds), AsyncTask, creating a new Thread, etc. There are plenty of ways to do things in the background or after a specified period of time.

Comment: @Guardanis I want only when your application is not in foreground then Handler, AsyncTask, thread can not be used

Comment: If you want it to run when the application is not currently being shown, then you should probably be using a service that runs in the background

Comment: @Guardanis but service does not repeat your job own, I want to know the ways to repeat the job using service

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AlarmManager will be good choice as its a system service and you don't need to create extra service for that. To start a AlarmManager you need a pending intent and a background task to do the heavy stuff.

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DownloadService.class);
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ViewPagerActivity.this,
    0, new Intent(ViewPagerActivity.this, DownloadService.class),
    PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);

if (alarmUp)
    am.cancel(sender);
```

You can use this code at the time of initialization of activity or onCreate(). Where DownloadService is a extend of BroadcastReceiver Class.

```
public class DownloadService extends BroadcastReceiver
```

inside `onReceive` method of this class you can do your periodic repeat task.

And this is how you can start your alarm and you put this code inside resume of activity or some other callback

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis(), globalData.serviceTimeInterval,
                sender);
```